# How to extract measurements and/or units from texts?

Tags: python, regex

#### Situation

Given are some titles with measuremnts and units in various combinations, I´m focused to extract the measurements and units with unit `m`.

```
1 Kabel0,3m
2 Kabel,0,3 m m 
3 Kabelx,0.3 m
4 Kabel 1m,
5 Kabel 1 m/
6 Kabel 1 HW-Y 2.0 m LAN/LAN RJ45/2xRJ45 Homeway f.2 unabh.Datennetz-Anwend.blau
7 Rundleitung 0,24 mm 2/ 250 m,8p   
8 Televes TV/RF-Empfängeranschlußkabel 10, 0 m weiss
```

#### Best try

```
(?P<match>(?P<value>\d+(?:\.|,|)\s*\d*)\s*(?<unit>m))
```

https://regex101.com/r/5yH4GN/1

Still struggling with the the line 7 - So how to exclude the `mm`?

#### Expected result

Hope somebody can give me a hint, to come closer to a solution.

| match | value | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0,3m | 0,3 | m |
| 0,3 m | 0,3 | m |
| 0.3 m | 0.3 | m |
| 1m | 1 | m |
| 1 m | 1 | m |
| 2.0 m | 2.0 | m |
| 250 m | 250 | m |
| 10, 0m | 10, 0 | m |

Comment: The link you provided has all the results as your expected output. I'm confused. What is the question?

Comment: I wanted to exclude the  `mm` from the matches, so `word boundary`  as mentioned by The fourth bird was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the unit m, optionally match the decimal part `\d+(?:[.,]\s*\d+)?` where the digits after the dot or comma are not optional.

You could add the dot and comma to a character class `[.,]` and add a word boundary `\b` after the first `m` to for example not match `mm`

```
(?P<match>(?P<value>\d+(?:[.,]\s*\d+)?)\s*(?<unit>m\b))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6MSzyb/1)

Comment: `word boundary` - Thanks, a super hint to continue at this point - So the results now fit.